# dataframe none inside static function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static-methods, class-variables

so I'm new to python and was facing an issue with initializing a dataframe inside a static method. Here is my code:

```
class class1:
     df = pd.DataFrame()

     @staticmethod
     def static_method_1(df):
          class1.df = returns_a_df()
          print(class1.df)

     @staticmethod
     def static_method_2():
          print(class1.df)               // Here, I get it as none
```

I'm calling it using:

```
class1.static_method_1(data)               // data is not empty here
class1.static_method_2()    

         // I get here that df is empty
```

Since, i'm initializing class1.df in static_method_1, why is it showing empty in static_method_2?I'm able to print it in static_method_1 but not in the other function
Any help is appreciated.

- returns_a_df(): will basically return a df with values
- I'm able to print in static_method_1 but not in static_method_2
- How can I initialise it in such a way that it is available to all static methods
- I'm not using using self here.

Comment: What is `returns_a_df()`?

Comment: returns_a_df() is just a function that returns a dataframe, so basically class1.df is a dataframe with some values

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use class variables and functions to achieve this:

```
class class1:
 
 def __init__(self):
      self.df = pd.DataFrame()

 def static_method_1(self,df):
      self.df = returns_a_df()
      print(self.df)

 def static_method_2(self):
      print(self.df)
```

And call the class using:

```
w = class1()
```

or remove the returns_a_df in **init** and call it seperately:

```
data = returns_a_df()
w = class1(data)
```

Comment: Okay thanks! it works